# Excel Dynamic Chart- Range Name based on IF formula not accepted as 'Series Name'

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have created a simple Dynamic Line Chart in Excel 2013 as seen below. As I change the Year in Cell D1, the Series on Y Axis changes accordingly. The X Axis series is static. When I use Excel Range Name V_Ser1 that derives its value based on IF function as Series Name, Excel does not like it.

[image]

The formula for V_Ser1 is very simple

```
=IF(Sheet2!$D$1=2013,"Cost 2013","Cost 2014")
```

The Formula is accepted but the Name V_Ser1 when entered in the ‘Series Name’ in Edit Series box is not accepted. The error as per below pic.

[image]
A Range Name that just points to Cell D1 is accepted (e.g. V_Ser as in first pic)
What exactly is going wrong, is there any constraint on what should go into name of data series in Excel Chart? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error shows when a range name is deleted while a series still uses that range name in the series definition. Check the chart source and remove all series that don't refer to valid range names.